# Normalize a many-to-many table

Tags: r, database-normalization

I have an input data.frame `combined` containing a many-to-many relationship that I would like to normalize into 2 tables. This input table contains the mixture composition for several different samples and locations.

I would like to derive 2 tables from this: one (`goal_1`) with location, sampleid, and a mixtureid; the second table should contain the actual mixture composition (`goal_2`).

```r
library(tidyverse) 

goal_1 = tribble(
  ~sampleID, ~location, ~MixtureID,
  1, "A", 1,
  2, "B", 2,
  3, "C", 3,
  4, "A", 4,
  5, "A", 1,
  6, "B", 2,
  7, "B", 2
)

goal_2 = tribble(
  ~MixtureID, ~element, ~conc_pct,
  1, "He", 0,
  1, "H", 10,
  1, "C", 0,
  1, "O", 0,
  1, "N", 0,
  1, "Ca", 90,
  1, "Cs", 0,
  2, "Si", 0,
  2, "S", 100,
  2, "V", 0,
  3, "Nb", 100,
  3, "Fe", 0,
  4, "C", 20,
  4, "H", 10,
  4, "S", 70
);

combined = left_join(goal_1, goal_2, by = "MixtureID", relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  select(-MixtureID)
```

Basically I want to reverse the operation of `combined = left_join(...)`

I can generate the goal_1 table partially with:

```r
goal_1a = distinct(combined, sampleID, location)
```

However I'm stuck on how to derive the `goal_2` table from the `combined` table.

Comment: In SQL databases many-to-many relationships often use three tables, not just two! What is the result you actually get in this "combined" table?

Comment: The `combined` table is my input, if can split it into 3 that's also ok.

Comment: First you have to know the logic of the data.

Answer (score 0):

1. If this is a many-to-many relationship, shouldn't this technically be a *full_join* instead of a *left_join*? (In this case, it seems to result in the same data)

```
combined <- full_join( goal_1, goal_2, 
    by = "MixtureID", relationship = "many-to-many" )
```

2. Using your existing left_join data set, then to normalize your `combined` data set, I would suggest you try something like this:

```
( table_1 <- combined |> distinct( sampleID, location ))
( table_2 <- combined |> distinct( sampleID, element, conc_pct ))
```

Then you could join the two and get the same 28 rows:

```
table_1 |> 
    inner_join( table_2, by = 'sampleID')
```

Comment: Thanks, combining your table1 and table2 results in the same output, but unfortunately table_2 is longer than goal_2 (I would like to have unique mixtures in goal_2)